# Unusal text appears on top of the WordPress web sites

Tags: wordpress, header, wordpress-theming

[image]

Please tell me how to delete that text.

Comment: What is the text you do not expect to see? It also help other to help you, if you show your source code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've printed something there, check your header.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you echoed something on your header file.